# set requirejs with closure compiler as an optimzer

Tags: playframework-2.0, requirejs, google-closure-compiler

I'm trying to get requirejs to use google closure compiler as an optimizer. 
I'm working under play2 framework, I added settings lines to my build.sbt:

```
 .settings(requireJs += "mainProd.js", requireJsShim += "build.js")
```

and in my build.js

```
optimize: 'closure',
```

when I hit 'dist', I get this error:

```
[error] (proj-web/*:playBuildRequireAssets) java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/protobuf/MessageOrBuilder
```

Note that if I set the optimize option to use optimize: 'uglify2', all is pass without errors.

Note#2
I tried to add closure setting ib my build.scala, again, without success.

```
.settings(closureCompilerOptions += "advancedOptimizations",
          closureCompilerOptions += "checkControlStructures",
          closureCompilerOptions += "checkTypes",
          closureCompilerOptions += "checkSymbols")
```

Any idea someone?